# Angular 2: Accessing list of attributes from component definition

Tags: angular, typescript

I am defining my own `<input>` component with label, layout, bootstrap classes, etc. So when I use it like this:

```
<my-input label="Street" [(ngModel)]="address.street"></my-input>
```

Then it will instantiate MyInputComponent, which will use a rich template to generate something like:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">{{ label }}</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input [(ngModel)]="value" class="form-control">
    </div>
</div>`
```

This is working great and I can access the "label" attribute just by using `@Input`:

```
@Component({...})
export class MyInputComponent {
    @Input() label = '';
```

Now that is great for just a few attributes. But the HTML standard `<input>` tag has literally dozens of attributes such as `type`, `min`, `max`, `placeholder`... and I don't want to have to define every single possible attribute as an `@Input` property of MyInputComponent.

Instead, I want to dynamically iterate over the attributes in `<my-input>` and copy them to the `<input>` element inside my template. I know I can access the list of attributes of the DOM element by using ElementRef in the constructor and then accessing its nativeElement property:

```
constructor(eref: ElementRef) {
    console.log("***", eref.nativeElement);
}
```

But accessing nativeElement is discouraged as a bad practice for several reasons (see https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/index/ElementRef-class.html).

So the question is: is there some way to access the list of attributes of `<my-input>` without resorting to directly reading the native browser DOM?

And likewise, once I have the list of attributes in a neutral, non-native way, how can I then propagate them to the `<input>` tag inside my template?

Answer (score 2):

I think you would be better of using transclusion to wrap your input in your fancy MyInputComponent. Have a look at the follow blog:

https://toddmotto.com/transclusion-in-angular-2-with-ng-content

Essentially you would change this:

```
<my-input label="Street" [(ngModel)]="address.street"></my-input>
```

To this:

```
<my-input label="Street">
    <input [(ngModel)]="address.street"class="form-control">
</my-input>
```

So you could still access all the properties of input easily and get the decoration that you want with little work.

Comment: Thank you, it looks great, I will read the article. I have heard about transclusion but never actually knew it was about this.

Anyway I am still curious on whether there is a way to access attributes of Angular 2 components on a clean, neutral and non-native way.

Comment: I tried to use transclusion, but it is not enough because the transcluded input also requires some Bootstrap setup such as `class="form-control"`. So either I force the user of my component to add such code every time, or I am back to having to manipulate the DOM to manually add the Bootstrap class.

Comment: P.S. I also tried `<ng-content [ngClass]="{'form-control': true }"></ng-content>`, but it had no effect whatsoever on the transcluded <input>.